# Jest test of submit event "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, api, jestjs, dom-events

I am trying to create a test for a submit button that fetches data from an API database I made. I am struggling to get the fake event input to the correct format for the function which triggers from my eventlistener. Currently, I am receiving the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

This is the function that is called when the form is submitted, destination is an object with a key of id and a value from the value attribute on the HTML

```
const selectDestination = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = document.querySelector('form');
    const destination =  {
        id: form.destination.value
        }
    console.log(destination)

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data/${destination.id}`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(appendPrice)
    .catch(console.warn)

}
```

And it is targetting this HTML code

```
<form>
        <label for="event">Choose a destination</label>
        <select name="destination" id="destination">
        <option value="1">Paris</option>
        <option value="2">Stockholm</option>
        <option value="3">Munich</option>
        <option value="4">New York</option>
        <option value="5">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    <input  id = "submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is the test I am trying to run with jest

```
describe('submit event', () => {
        it('listens for event when submit button pressed', () => {
            const fakeE = {
                preventDefault: jest.fn(),
                    target: {
                       destination : { value: '1' },
                    }
                }
            app.selectDestination(fakeE)
            expect(app.selectDestination).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
        
    })
```

I have been messing around with the syntax for a while now and still cannot get it to work. I think the issue has something to do with the way I have targeted the HTML, but I am not sure how I would change this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The full code is on my github here: https://github.com/qlanphere/travelDestinationPrices

Answer (score 0):

You should target the select input not the form element. In the fetch request you should also return data and work on it.

```js
const selectDestination = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let chooseDestination = document.querySelector('#destination');
    const destination =  {
        id: chooseDestination.value
        }
    console.log(destination)

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data/${destination.id}`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
      // do something with data...
    }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
    })

}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried that, the code still works but I am still receiving an error on my test.

expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function selectDestination]

It looks like the format of my test is still incorrect

Comment: Try to correct catch with `.catch(error) {console.log(error);}`. I'm going to edit my answer...